# ContentDefinitionParameters with Default Value

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I know how to send extra information during signin.

```
<ContentDefinitionParameters>
   <Parameter Name="campaignId">{OAUTH-KV:customUi}</Parameter>
</ContentDefinitionParameters>
```

The only place I will be using this value is in the Content Definitions like below

```
<ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
    <LoadUri>cdn.mydomain.com/{OAUTH-KV:ui-version}/thepage.html</LoadUri>
    <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:1.2.0</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
    </Metadata>

    <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
        <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.signuporsignin.en" />
    </LocalizedResourcesReferences>

</ContentDefinition>
```

The problem with this is that if the front end, does not add the ui-version to the query string the login will error. I was wondering if it was possible to give this a default value? That way, if the parameter is missing, I can default it and the login will work.

Anyone any ideas on how best to achieve this?

Comment: did you get any solution for this issue, I am facing the same

Comment: no I did not get a solution. Moved jobs about 18 months ago and no longer using B2C in my new job I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append a static query parameter using custom policy use `input claims`

```
 </CryptographicKeys>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myQueryParam" DefaultValue="staticParamValue"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
```

this will append as `&myQueryParam=staticParamValue`.

If the input claim is not using a defaultValue, it will send whatever value is inside the claim at this point in time of policy execution. It could be a [claims resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#non-protocol-parameters) too.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not how I'm using the parameter. It is only used for setting the ContentDefinition location. I've updated the question, to try and show this